# Android studio recyclerview error when deleting items - Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have an error when I delete all the items from my `recyclerview`. No problem when I delete one specific item, the error appears when I delete the last one (I mean, when I delete everything). So here is my code

```
viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.rmvPerson).setOnClickListener(new     View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(position).removeValue();
                    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    dataBase.child(getRef(position).getKey().toString().trim()).child("usuario").removeValue();
                }
            });
```

So the error is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: uyenterteinment.haynoche, PID: 7251
              java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
                  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                  at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseArray.getItem(FirebaseArray.java:50)
                  at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:155)
                  at uyenterteinment.haynoche.EventSingleActivity$3$3.onClick(EventSingleActivity.java:239)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5698)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22557)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here as you can see, it sais

```
at uyenterteinment.haynoche.EventSingleActivity$3$3.onClick(EventSingleActivity.java:239)
```

this line is:

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(position).removeValue();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: my dear friend @VishvaDave did you read the question properly check the exception **`IndexOutOfBoundsException : Invalid index 1, size is 1`**

Comment: @NileshRathod Ok got it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) on the `firebaseRecyclerAdapter` as such

```
viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.rmvPerson).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    var index = position - 1;
                    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(index).removeValue();
                    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    dataBase.child(getRef(position).getKey().toString().trim()).child("usuario").removeValue();
                    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

And to prevent the exception, just substract 1 from the `position` because indexes are zero-based thus meaning the first item has index 0.

Answer (score 0):

Update your view after removing item from `recyclerview`, By adding "`notifyDataSetChanged()`" after removing item.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is use for you

```
viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()
```

where you are click item

```
viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.rmvPerson).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).removeValue();
            dataBase.child(getRef(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getKey().toString().trim()).child("usuario").removeValue();
            firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after removing the value from recyclerview, Call **notifyDataSetChanged()**  from the adapter to refresh the recyclerview with the edited data.So that the size of the ArrayList will also be updated.

```
viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.rmvPerson).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                  /*remove value*/
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```